# How do I align images to the bottom of a nested div (in bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to align different size images to the bottom of a div but the images are also in their own divs so the other answers don't work.

I have the following HTML:

```
    <div class="row footer-links">
        <section>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>
                    Proudly presented and sponsored by
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 logo-links">
                <div class="row logo-bottom">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 logo-border col-md-offset-1">
                        <img id="rasv" class="center-block" src="img/rasv.png" alt="RASV logo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 logo-border">
                        <img class="center-block" src="img/victoria-farmers.png" alt="Victoria Farmers logo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 logo-border">
                        <img class="center-block" src="img/anz.png" alt="ANZ logo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 logo-border">
                        <img class="center-block" src="img/pwc.png" alt="PWC logo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 logo-border">
                        <img class="center-block" src="img/vac.png" alt="VAC logo">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

I used the following CSS:

```
.logo-border {
    border-right: 1px solid #d1d3d4;
    height: 54px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Here is a [Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoBapN) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were really close.

The reason it wasn't working was because the columns are floated. Due to this, the elements weren't behaving like a `table-cell`, therefore rendering `vertical-align: bottom` useless.

You could simply add `float: none` and it will work as desired.

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rarZve)

```
.logo-bottom .logo-border {
  border-right: 1px solid #d1d3d4;
  height: 54px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
}
```

As a side note, I increased the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of the selector `.logo-border` to `.logo-bottom .logo-border` so that `float: left` was overridden.